# Where is NHibernate 3.1 Session Query Method?

Tags: nhibernate, session

I am a NHibernate novice to say the least.

I'm using NHibernate 3.1 and I'm trying to implement a generic repository using the generic session Query method. However, I cannot see it in my Visual Studio IDE Intellisense. I can only see QueryOver - which I'm not sure if it's meant to replace Query method. If so, why did they not leave Query but with a message indicating it has been deprecated as per convention?

Please someone help - I'll be eternally grateful.

Many thanks S.O.F community.

Comment: Sorry folks. Figured this one out. All I had to do was import the NHibernate.Linq namespace. In brief insert:

using NHibernate.Linq

Rookie mistake but might help someone. The concerned code was:


public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
  return Transact(() => Session.Query<T>().Take(1000).GetEnumerator());
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not deprecated. They're different things. `session.Query<T>()` lets you use the LINQ provider, while `QueryOver` is a different API, also Expression based but actually more similar to the Criteria API.

As you already figured out, you need to open the NHibernate.Linq namespace to use the LINQ provider.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio for the comments. Very helpful indeed.